# T-SQL substring() behavior

Tags: t-sql, substring

I encountered a bit of code within the book I've been reading that has me questioning the `SUBSTRING()` function's behavior.   The code is supposed to search a NYSIIS Replacement table (phonetic encoding example) and replace the middle 'N-gram' of an input string based on the location 'End' 'Mid' or 'Start' in the table. an excerpt is provided below:

NYSIIS Replacement Table:

```
Location NGram Replacement

Mid      A     A
Mid      AW    AA
Mid      E     A
Mid      EV    AF
Mid      EW    AA
Mid      I     A
```

```
USE [AdventureWorks]

DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(100) = N'NEVADA';

DECLARE @Replacement NVARCHAR(10);

DECLARE @i INT;

SET @i = 1;

WHILE @i <= LEN (@Result)

BEGIN

    SET @Replacement = NULL;

    -- Grab the middle-of-name replacement n-gram

    SELECT TOP(1)  @Replacement = Replacement                   
    FROM dbo.NYSIIS_Replacements                         
    WHERE Location = N'Mid'
        AND SUBSTRING(@Result, @i, LEN(NGram)) = NGram
    ORDER BY LEN(NGram) DESC;


    SET @Replacement = COALESCE(@Replacement, SUBSTRING(@Result, @i, 1));   


    -- If we found a replacement, apply it

    SET @Result = STUFF(@Result, @i, LEN(@Replacement), @Replacement) 

    -- Move on to the next n-gram

    SET @i = @i + COALESCE(LEN(@Replacement), 1);


END;

SELECT @Result;
```

When the `SUBSTRING()` function encounters 2 possible matches using 'NEVADA' as an example ('E' and 'EV' in the table) how does it 'know' to use the 2 letter string as opposed to the one?  Is this the expected behavior for `SUBSTRING()`?

I would assume the `@Replacement` variable would contain both 'A' and 'AF' but when debugging it only appears to contain 'N' in the first iteration and 'AF' in the second.

Also I could not understand why `TOP` and `ORDER BY` were included in this example.  Commenting them out produces the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause uses the length of the pattern and sorts in descending order, hence the longest match will occur first.  The `TOP` clause limits the results to the first row.  Removing the `ORDER BY` clause makes the result unpredictable.

`COALESCE` is used to set `@Replacement` to either the replacement pattern, or the character at position `@i` in the `@Result` string if no pattern match was found.

Comment: that would make sense.  thanks.  The results without TOP or ORDER BY would be unordered I'm assuming, although I've only returned the 2 letter string every time I've run it.